# How to rotate image when expand recyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

In my application, I want **expand** and **collapse** `recyclerView`!
I can expand and collapse `recyclerView` and for this I use this **library** : https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

I want when click on `recyclerView` (**expand** or **collapse**) rotate arrow image!
I write below code in `viewHolder` class but not work and not rotate arrow image!
**ParentViewHolder codes:**

```
public class seasonParentViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {

    private TextView row_epGuideParent_Title, row_epGuideParent_Count, row_epGuideParent_Date;
    private ImageView row_epGuideParent_arrowImg;

    public seasonParentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        row_epGuideParent_Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_epGuideParent_Title);
        row_epGuideParent_Count = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_epGuideParent_Count);
        row_epGuideParent_Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_epGuideParent_Date);
        row_epGuideParent_arrowImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.row_epGuideParent_arrowImg);
    }

    public void setGenreTitle(ExpandableGroup title) {
        if (title instanceof ExpandableModel) {
            row_epGuideParent_Title.setText(title.getTitle());
            row_epGuideParent_Count.setText(((ExpandableModel) title).getCount());
            row_epGuideParent_Date.setText(((ExpandableModel) title).getDate());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void expand() {
        animateExpand();
    }

    @Override
    public void collapse() {
        animateCollapse();
    }

    private void animateExpand() {
        RotateAnimation rotate =
                new RotateAnimation(360, 180, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(300);
        rotate.setFillAfter(true);
        row_epGuideParent_arrowImg.setAnimation(rotate);
    }

    private void animateCollapse() {
        RotateAnimation rotate =
                new RotateAnimation(180, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotate.setDuration(300);
        rotate.setFillAfter(true);
        row_epGuideParent_arrowImg.setAnimation(rotate);
    }
}
```

**Called expand and collapse in library :**

```
public abstract class GroupViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener {

  private OnGroupClickListener listener;

  public GroupViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if (listener != null) {
      if (listener.onGroupClick(getAdapterPosition())) {
        collapse();
      } else {
        expand();
      }
    }
  }

  public void setOnGroupClickListener(OnGroupClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
  }

  public void expand() {}

  public void collapse() {}

}
```

How can I fix this problem and rotate arrow image when click on `recyclerView` (**expand** or **collapse**)  ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** You have to use `startAnimation()` for your `ImageView` instead of `setAnimation()`.

> `void setAnimation (Animation animation)`
>
> Sets the next animation to play for this view. If you want the
>   animation to play immediately, use
>   startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation) instead [...]

(quoted from [developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)))

Comment: @Kir - simply exchange `setAnimation()` for `startAnimation()` in your two methods `expand()` and `collapse()`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void expand() {
    arrow_icn.setRotation(180);
}

@Override
public void collapse() {
    arrow_icn.setRotation(0);
}
```